# Performance issue in conversion of json to bson

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

This is a snippet from a java function, we take as an argument, a `com.google.gson.JsonArray` and then inside a loop, we convert each of the json elements, which are very small in size, to corresponding  `org.bson.Document` document and then after the loop is completed, we use the  `com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertMany` method to insert all the above created documents.

```
List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    documents.add(Document.parse(jsonArray.get(i).toString()));
}
```

Now, the problem which we are facing is that the conversion of `json` to `bson` is taking huge amount of time.

Please suggest the best possible approach of converting the json to bson document or jsonArray to List of documents.

Comment: how much is **huge amount of time** ? can you please share the stats?

Comment: @sidgate Problem is with CPU utilization, inside the loop Process CPU load reaches around 100%, how can that be brought down?